# Removing padding or margins from Bokeh Figures

Tags: python, bokeh, figure

is it possible to get rid of the padding (or margin) on the sides of bokeh figures? 
I've been looking at various figures and they all seem to have this blank area to their left. I also tried changing the borders 
for example:  `s1.min_border_left = 0 or change it to s1.min_border_left = 40`

but it doesn't seem to do the job, it changes the border but somehow it seems that there is a padding that is fixed and not changable, an example of the area i'd like to get rid of:
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1luy.jpg)
so is it possible to get rid of that and just have the figure stick to the left side of the browser?

[Bokeh Figures and Borders](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#border)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the bokeh server, you can add an external css sheet with something like this to modify the margins.

```
html, body {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 99%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open generated HTML page and replace width 90% with 100%

Answer (score 0):

based on the other answers, here is snippet that may come in handy:

```
import os
import re
import tempfile
import webbrowser
import time

from bokeh.io import output_file, save


def save_bokeh_nomargins(plot, filename):
    """
    Saves a bokeh plot/layout without having the left margin.
    """
    # Strategy:
    #  1. save the plot to a temp file
    #  2. change the offending line of code
    #  3. save the result to the destination file
    ftemp = tempfile.mktemp()
    try:
        output_file(ftemp)
        save(plot)
        with open(ftemp) as ftemph, open(filename, "w") as fouth:
            fouth.write(re.sub("width: 90%;", "width: 100%;", ftemph.read(), count=1))
    finally:
            os.remove(ftemp)


def show_bokeh_nomargins(plot):
    """
    Displays a bokeh plot/layout without having the left margin.
    """
    ftemp = tempfile.mktemp()
    try:
        save_bokeh_nomargins(plot, ftemp)
        webbrowser.open(ftemp)
        time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        os.remove(ftemp)
```

I should note that this is a bit hacky, and it might go wrong if you have `width: 90%` anywhere else in your the file.